# installing app from a Storageacct via template.json file... we need the storageName and Key to be passed through a parameter so its not hardcoded

Tags: azure, parameter-passing, azure-rm-template, azure-storage-account

ive been banging my head against the wall about this one as i cannot figure out how to get the StorageAccountName and Key to be passed to the template from a parameters file.
i am struggling to find any clear guide or examples of this...

what were trying to achieve is this.
we need Sophos AV to be installed as part of a VM deployment via the arm template.
when the storage account details are hardcoded into the template file the arm template works and sophos.ps1 (which holds the install stuff runs)

im very close to finishing a custom deployment script for us but im stuck on this thing as I dont want sensitive information like the storage account key hardcoded into the template.

the snippet of the template file below has the storageaccountname and key hardcoded into the template.

*updated*

- added defaultvalue for storageAccountResourceGroupName
- added storageAccountResourceGroupName to storageAccountName
- updated storageAccountName

**template.json**

```
   "parameters": {

"storageAccountResourceGroupName":{
            "type": "string",
            "defaultValue": "RSG2"
"storageAccountName": {
            "type": "string",
       "defaultValue": "filesstgacct"
{
        "type": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/extensions",
        "name": "[concat(parameters('virtualMachineName'), '/MyCustomScriptExtension')]",
        "apiVersion": "2015-05-01-preview",
        "location": "[parameters('location')]",
        "dependsOn": [ "[concat('Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/',parameters('virtualMachineName'))]" ],
        "tags": "[parameters('tags')]",
        "properties": { "publisher": "Microsoft.Compute",
        "type": "CustomScriptExtension", "typeHandlerVersion": "1.3", "autoUpgradeMinorVersion": true,
        "settings": { 
            "fileUris": [ "https://storage-account-name.blob.core.windows.net/scripts/sophos.ps1" 
            ]
        },
        "protectedSettings": {
            "commandToExecute": "powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -File sophos.ps1",
            "storageAccountName": "[parameters('storageAccountName')]",
            "storageAccountKey": "[listKeys(resourceid(parameters['storageAccountResourceGroupName'], 'Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', parameters('storageAccountName')), providers('Microsoft.Storage', 'storageAccounts').apiVersions[0]).keys[0].value]"
        
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> can the storageaccountname and key be stored in the parameters file?
> if yes then how do i link the 2 together?

Yes. I believe the reason you're not able to read the value is because you're not specifying the parameters properly. Please try something like:

```
"parameters": {
    "storageAccountName": {
        "type": "string",
        "defaultValue": "storage-account-name"
    },
    "storageAccountKey": {
        "type": "string",
        "defaultValue": "storage-account-key"
    }
}
```

> alternatively is it possible to refences the storage account key
> directly from the template/parameter file meaning the key is never
> hardcoded?

Actually this is the recommended way that you do not hardcode the storage account key in your template file. What you can do is fetch the key dynamically using [`listKeys`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/template-functions-resource#list) template function. All you have to do is provide the complete resource id of your storage account and API version.

You would probably use something like:

```
"storageAccountKey": "[listKeys(resourceid(resourceGroup().name, 'Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', parameters('storageAccountName')), providers('Microsoft.Storage', 'storageAccounts').apiVersions[0]).keys[0].value]"
```

and ARM template processor will automatically fetch the account key for your storage account.

Comment: hey mate.. thanks for the info.
you are most likely correct... i havent specified the parameter correctly.

in regards to the listkey template function... yes i agree this would definitely be the favourable way of doing it... i just dont fully understand how it works and how it refences everything...

the listkey line you mentioned above, does that go into the template file or the parameter file?

i will try both of your suggestions tomorrow and post back

thanks again!

Comment: `the listkey line you mentioned above, does that go into the template file or the parameter file` - Neither. It actually makes a REST API request to your Storage account and fetches the keys dynamically.

Comment: ok... but where do i add that line to? 
as in which file and in what spot?

Comment: If I'm understanding correctly... The listkey will replace the storageaccountkey entry in the template where the key is needed as part of the application install I'm doing... Does that sound right?

Comment: Your understanding is correct. You can define your key as a variable and assign value using listkeys function if you need to use this key in multiple places.

Comment: Ok thanks.. I think it's making more sense. I'll also remove the hard coded key parameter when I try the list key every... I will post back tomorrow! Thanks again .. really appreciate your help so far

Comment: ok i added the storageaccountname to the parameters area in the template.json file and updated the storageaccountkey line so it contains the listkey function.
 
i then tried deploying but it failed as it cannot find the StorageAccount

The Resource 'Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/storage-account-name' under resource group 'RSG1' was not found.

the deployment is creating a VM in RSG1, but the Sophos install files are stored in another RSG..

so how do i specify the storage account thats needed?

Comment: looking at the following link 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/error-not-found
it says... to reference a storage account in another resource group, use:
'"[reference(resourceId('exampleResourceGroup', 'Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', 'myStorage'), '2017-06-01')]"'
when i set this as either a parameter or variable it doesnt work and the same error shows up that the storage account cannot be found in the RSG... really not sure on the syntax here...

Comment: Please edit your question and add the updated template.json and parameters.json file and I will take a look. Thanks.

Comment: hi... im a bit confused as to where im meant to set these parameter settings.. so for the moment ive removed any the entries from the parameter.json file and left it all in the template.json file. 

ive updated the original question with the new template.json entries that relate to my question... let me know if theres anything else you need.

thanks again!

Comment: So for storage account name, you just have to specify the name and not the storage account id. Other than that, your template looks fine to me. Can you please try by changing that?

Comment: umm do you mean replace storage-account-name with the actual real name of the storageaccount? (eg. filesstgacct)  I have tried that before and it spat out the same error... that it cannot find filestgacct in the resource group that the VM is being deployed to...

VM is being deployed to RSG1
filestgacct exists in RSG2

i feel like the template isnt referencing the correct RSG

Comment: Aah...I see it now. You're correct. Basically you're using `resourceGroup()` function and that will give you the name of the resource group in which the template is deployed. Please add one more parameter called `storageAccountResourceGroupName` and set its value to `RSG2`. Then use this parameter in your listKeys function call.

Comment: Something like `"storageAccountKey": "[listKeys(resourceid(parameters["storageAccountResourceGroupName"], 'Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', parameters('storageAccountName')), providers('Microsoft.Storage', 'storageAccounts').apiVersions[0]).keys[0].value]"`

Comment: ok im on it... will post back soon...

Comment: no good... same error... still trying to find the stgacct in the incorrect RSG.
ive updated the template.json file in my question with what it looks like now...

Comment: You need to change `storageAccountName` parameter value and set it to `filesstgacct`.

Comment: wooopsie... one sec... changing that now and testing...
updating question with correct syntax

Comment: still no good :(
its still trying to find filesstgacct in the incorrect RSG

Comment: so heres something interesting. when i look at the deployment information for the VM.
if i click on redeploy and scroll down the custom deployment blade, it shows the correct Storage account Name.
so that to me says it is detecting it correctly?

Comment: I guess so. Were your resources deployed successfully?

Comment: the template is pretty basic and all it does is deploy a VM with the associated OS DISK and a NIC.. and yes they deploy fine.
it just fails on the app install of sophos ....

Comment: another thing... during the deployment if i click on the inputs blade i can see all the parameters specified in the template.json file. so things like location, which domain its going to join, tags, subnetname, vnet, vm name, vm RSG, osdisktype ... etc.
the only one i cannot see is the storageAccountResourceGroupName .... this input is not showing at all... 

its as if that variable hasnt applied at all to the template file...

Comment: looks like my powershell session had jammed up.. restarted and getting this Error: Code=InvalidTemplate; Message=Deployment template language expression evaluation failed: 'Unable to parse language expression
     | 'listKeys(resourceid(parameters['storageAccountResourceGroupName'], 'Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', parameters('storageAccountName')),
     | providers('Microsoft.Storage', 'storageAccounts').apiVersions[0]).keys[0].value': expected token 'LeftParenthesis' and actual 'LeftSquareBracket'.'.

Comment: is there a square bracket missing somewhere?

Comment: My mistake! Please try to change `parameters['storageAccountResourceGroupName']` to `parameters('storageAccountResourceGroupName')`.

Comment: no problem... ive been playing around with the brackets and was wondering if those are correct!
im having some weird issue with my powershell at the moment where its not refreshing itself... whenever i run the deployment with the updated brackets it spits out an error showing the square ones.... not sure whats going on with it at the moment.
anyways i need to head off now but will come back to this tomorrow... i think its almost there, just need to figure out these brackets.... thanks again for all your help... been amazing! cheers!

Comment: i ended up rebooting and that seemed to have fixed my powershell session... the deployment is now picking up the storageaccount and storageaccountresourcegroup !
in the deployment info the storage account is showing up with a green tick...
when running the deployment i get the following error which im now trying to figure out.... 
permissions issue? is it trying to run the installer before the vm has started?

Comment: {
    "status": "Failed",
    "error": {
        "code": "VMExtensionProvisioningError",
        "message": "VM has reported a failure when processing extension 'MyCustomScriptExtension'. Error message: \"Command execution finished, but failed because it returned a non-zero exit code of: '1'. Command execution may have been interrupted by a VM restart\"\r\n\r\nMore information on troubleshooting is available at https://aka.ms/VMExtensionCSEWindowsTroubleshoot "
    }
}

Comment: found the logs on the vm for the customscriptextension and ive found this
**[ERROR] Command execution finished, but failed because it returned a non-zero exit code of: '1'. Command execution may have been interrupted by a VM restart**
so the install file is being copied to the vm and i can see it there... 
I ran the install file as admin and it installed sophos ... i suspect that the customscriptextension may not be running the sophos.ps1 file as admin

Comment: Looks like there's an issue with your custom script extension code. Unfortunately I know nothing about that. I would recommend asking a separate question for that by sharing your code there.

Comment: yep will do.. thanks for all your help with this... got the storage account working as i wanted.. now to resolve this permissions issue.. or whatever is causing the PS1 file to error ... thanks again!

Comment: do you know if its possible to use the storageaccountkey value inside the sophos.ps1 script?... as in can i inject/import that value into that ps1 file?

Comment: You should be able to do it. Please see this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/deployment-script-template.

Comment: thanks but we decided to go down a slightly different path.... we got rid of the PS1 file and referenced the sophossetup.exe directly from blob.
had an issue where the ps1 file had a hardcoded storagekey and we didnt want that so installing directly from the blob bypasses that issue entirely. 
installing Sophos was the main goal here and nothing else... and ive got it working as expected. Script deploys the vm with all necessary variables, tags etc and then installs sophos and registers the vm with sophos. thanks again for your input... really got me over the line! cheers!